# garbage value is being printed when a two multi dimensional array is sent as a parameter to a function

Tags: arrays, c, function, matrix

This program i wrote to multiply any kind of matrix if it satisfies condition

most of the code is used to take input only the part where the function needs to take input appears to be the area of trouble,
not able to get correct results and also getting garbage value in the resultant matrix.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void multiply(int,int,int,int,int [][100],int [][100]);
void main()
{
    int i,j,e;
    int m,n,p,q;
    int a[m][n],b[p][q];
    printf("\n enter m and n");
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    printf("\n enter the matrix elements");
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    printf("\n enter p and q");
    scanf("%d %d",&p,&q);
    printf("\n enter the matrix elements");
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)
            scanf("%d",&b[i][j]);
    printf("if u want to multliply the matrix enter 1");
    scanf("%d",&e);
    {
    printf("a matrix n is columns and m is rows \n");
    for(int i =0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);

        }
         printf("\n");
    }
  printf("a matrix q is columns and p is rows \n");
     for(int i =0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",b[i][j]);

        }
         printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    if(e==1&&n==p)

    multiply(m,n,p,q,a,b);

}
}
void multiply(int m,int n,int p,int q,int a[][100],int b[][100])
{
    printf("a matrix n is columns and m is rows \n");
    for(int i =0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);

        }
         printf("\n");
    }
  printf("a matrix q is columns and p is rows \n");
     for(int i =0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d ",b[i][j]);

        }
         printf("\n");
    }
    int s[m][q],sum=0,i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
         s[i][j]=0;
            for(k=0;k<n;k++)
            {
                s[i][j]=s[i][j]+a[i][k]*b[k][j];
            }
        printf("\t %d",s[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

How to fix this problelm?

Comment: Are you setting `n` to 1000 in `int a[m][n]` when `scanf` asks for the input? otherwise you are passing a mess. The compiler uses arithmetic based on `sizeof(int) * 1000` in `multiply()`, if you set the `n` to something different you get wrong values.

Comment: How can you declare dimensions of `a` and `b` arrays, if `m`, `n`, `p` and `q` has no values yet? C++ is sequential language, it should be done after scanf

Comment: What language are you using `C` or `C++`?  This: `int m,n,p,q; int a[m][n],b[p][q];` is not valid C++, even if those `int` variables are initialized.

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: Language used is c

Comment: One problem is the dimensions of the array parameters in the prototype of `multiply`. It should be `void multiply(int m,int n,int p,int q,int a[][n],int b[][q])`. The forward declaration can use `void multiply(int,int,int,int,int [][*],int [][*]);`.

Answer (score 0):

At least this problem:

Code has *undefined bahvaior* (UB) as the value of `m, n, p, q` are not certainly positive as the time of array `a, b` definition.

```
int m,n,p,q;
int a[m][n],b[p][q];
```

Change to:

```
int m,n,p,q;
// int a[m][n],b[p][q];
printf("\n enter m and n");
// scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
if (scanf("%d %d",&m,&n) != 2 || m <= 0 || n <= 0) {
  puts("Bad input");
  return -1;
}
int a[m][n];
```